# Retrieve Jquery variable using bash CGI

Tags: javascript, bash, cgi

I have the following javascript file:

```
$.ajax({
    url: './cgi-bin/make_dir.sh',
    data: {
        'myString' : 'myDirectory'
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('OK');
    }
});
```

And I would like my bash cgi script to retrieve the value of myString.
Is this possible using bash cgi scripting?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the CGI server you're using, but usually, you can access your URL values through the `$QUERY_STRING` environment variable. You'll need some string manipulation to get at the `myString` value, decoded, without the rest of the query string.

Be sure to read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/security_tips.html